# Why does the RedHat dotnet core vulnerability require rebuilding your application?

Tags: linux, .net-core, redhat

The recent dotnet core [RedHat vulnerablility](https://linuxsecurity.com/advisories/red-hat/redhat-rhsa-2020-0134-01-critical-net-core-on-red-hat-enterprise-linux-11-33-10) says in the description:

> Users must rebuild their applications to pick up the fixes.

What would require you to rebuild your application to pickup a framework fix?

Comment: It's quite simple, just update the sdk and runtime and execute dotnet build on your solution 

Comment: Because Microsoft carefully documented the steps at https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/403 and https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/402 You can read the articles and see why you have to rebuild your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Core 2.1 in RHEL ships without ASP.NET Core.

When you build your ASP.NET Core application, it picks up these things from NuGet.

Hence, you need to re-build it, to get the patched version.

Note that .NET Core 3.0 and 3.1 ships with ASP.NET Core and that is why you may have seen Red Hat Security Advisory for these versions, and not for 2.1 - because 2.1 that we ship, does not *actually* contain any security fixes.

You should not need to rebuild it with .NET Core 3.0 or 3.1. since they include ASP.NET Core. (If such note was present, it was by mistake due to last minute decision to ship 2.1 in separate advisory and this note was not removed.)

Comment: Perhaps I should have also noted that you do need to rebuild 3.x ones as well, if they're published as self-contained applications, since that would package everything with the version at the time of the build and not use anything from the framework.